# Pros & cons to using constants in place of css class names for razor views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, razor

**Background**

I work on an international team of developers. I'm constantly finding issues with misspelled class names causing issues with formatting.  The responses I'm looking for has nothing to do with finding better, more thorough, or more competent coders.

I'd like to get some feedback on performance hits, gotchas, and any other pros/cons for implementing something similar to the code I've written below.

**Example**

This example is a very simple version of what I've been considering and just to be clear, the field names we are using are NOT Field1, Field2, etc.

```
<div class="@Constants.CssClassNames.ColMd12">
  <div class="@Constants.CssClassNames.ColMd2"><label class="@Constants.CssClassNames.ControlLabel">@Labeling.Field1:</label></div>
  <div class="@Constants.CssClassNames.ColMd2">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Field1)</div>
  <div class="@Constants.CssClassNames.ColMd2"><label class="@Constants.CssClassNames.ControlLabel">@Labeling.Field2:</label></div>
  <div class="@Constants.CssClassNames.ColMd2">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Field2)</div>
  <div class="@Constants.CssClassNames.ColMd2"><label class="@Constants.CssClassNames.ControlLabel">@Labeling.Field3:</label></div>
  <div class="@Constants.CssClassNames.ColMd2">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Field3)</div>
```

**Why am I considering this?**

1. I'm pretty much the only dev here with any real knowledge of CSS that approaches a successful output as "Form+Function", and not just "Function" alone.
2. When there are UI issues, I'm usually the person that has to take time away from my own work to help others, so I'm trying to find a way to mitigate those support time drains
3. General curiosity regarding constants vs strings in a razor view

I've considered the recompilation of the Constants DLL if there are changes, but our production environment is set up to support this rather easily, and naming the constants more generically could help ease the pain of renaming, however, I'm looking for thoughts on this in other areas (especially performance related thoughts or perhaps if any of you that care to run a performance check on the diff, that's a big help).

If you have any suggestions on ways I could check the performance on my own (without having to add references to the project), I'd also appreciate that.

Thanks everyone in advance for your input.

Comment: Isn't there some css testing framework you can implement?

Comment: Are you referring to css validators for bootstrap?

Comment: Performance should not be an issue - it would be insignificant (and you can use the `StopWatch` class to measure assigning your constants to say a hundred variables if you really want to)

Comment: You might also consider an `enum` rather than constants - `class="@Bootstrap.FormControl"`